# How to modify grid-area of the element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

I am trying to do carousel in testimonials section. I have used grid to create the layout. So I would want to decrease each element position in the grid colums by -1 each time the item disappears and new one is being displayed.

My site:
https://wandawix.github.io/online-zoo-js/index.html

My full code:
https://github.com/WandaWix/online-zoo-js

`

```
/ Testimonials carousel ----------------------------------------------------------
// every testimonial is a slide, 1 2 3 4 -> click 2 3 4 5 -> click 3 4 5 6 -> 4 5 6 7 -> 5 6 7 8 -> 6 7 8 1

const sliders = document.querySelector('#testiInput'); //input name?


const p = document.querySelector('#valueTestimonials');

// console.log(p.innerHTML = 'lul');
const showNumber = () => {




    let testi1 = document.querySelector('.testi1');
    let testi2 = document.querySelector('.testi2');
    let testi3 = document.querySelector('.testi3');
    let testi4 = document.querySelector('.testi4');
    let testi5 = document.querySelector('.testi5');
    let testi6 = document.querySelector('.testi6');
    let testi7 = document.querySelector('.testi7');
    let testi8 = document.querySelector('.testi8');
    // console.log(testi1);
    
    let slide2 = document.querySelectorAll('.slide2');
    // console.log(slide2);
    let testimonials = [testi1, testi2, testi3, testi4, testi5, testi6, testi7, testi8];
    // console.log(testimonials);
    



    p.innerText = sliders.value;
    // console.log(sliders);
    let testiIndex = sliders.value;
    console.log(testiIndex);
    for(let i=0; i < testiIndex; i++) {
      slide2[i].style.display = 'none';
 
    }
    
    let lastSlide = testiIndex + 4;
    for(let i=testiIndex; i < lastSlide&& i < slide2.length; i++){
        slide2[i].style.display = 'block';
  
    }
    for(let i = lastSlide; i < 8; i++) {
        slide2[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}

sliders.addEventListener('change', showNumber);
```

`

I know this code isn't supposed to work but I want something like this
`

```
 // slide 2 should be decreased by 1 column 

    slide2[i].style.gridArea = ' x / x-1 / x / x-1';
```

`

Comment: How about element.setAttribute("style", "grid-area: x / x-1 / x / x-1') ??

Comment: I wonder how to write those x corretly in js. As I wrote them as only representation of current numbers in css which is for example in css file. Grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3 which I would want to be Grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2. So I dont have any x in js yet